# unlink() not working in PHP with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, unlink

I have problem with using unlink() in PHP...
See code:

JS:

```
$(".delete").on("click", function() {
var id = $(this).data("id");
$("#status").text("Deleted");
$.post("adminServer.php", { id: id }, function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(data);
});
```

});

PHP:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `upload_img` WHERE `id` = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$target = "/uploads/".$row['image'];

chmod($target, 0777);

unlink($target);

$sql = "DELETE FROM `upload_img` WHERE `id` = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if ($result == true) {
   $check = "Sucessfully deleted";
} else {
   $check = "Error while deleting";
}

echo json_encode($check);
```

it does not tell me the error and image is not deleted...

I do not know why this does not work... Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check the log?

Comment: @JackSkeletron I tried, I did not find...

Comment: Most likely PHP process doesn't have rights to do this. Try return the chmod response with some http code (goes faster) : if(!chmod($target, 0777)) http_response_code(500);

Comment: Is the target the right path? It seems to be referred to the root of FS. I mean, it should be `./uploads/image.jpg` if referred to the same folder of the script.

Comment: You may not have access to it, even after chmod. If the web server user does not own the file, the script will be unable to chmod it.

Comment: @JackSkeletron Nothing changed...

Comment: The file is a vaild file? Can you add and post the result of `var_dump(is_file($target))`

Comment: @JackSkeletron bool(false)

Comment: So that's not the right path or a regular file.

Comment: @JackSkeletron Ok, I will check

Comment: @JackSkeletron But this is right path to file... I don't know why is bool(false)..

Comment: You sould try adding the root path. Something like: $target = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/".$row['image'];

Comment: `var_dump(__DIR__)` to check where your script is located. Then check if the path in $target could be resolved in the right one you need. I mean if the dump returns something like `/var/www/yoursite/yourfolder/` and the image is in `/var/www/yoursite/uploads/` then you should write `../uploads/image.jpg`